# Table of Contents on the FAQ

Tags: feature-request

Could anyone with sufficient powers edit the FAQ so that it has a TOC on top, as MO's does? Changing the formatting so each section stands more separated from others would also help making it less of a mess...

Comment: I would, if I'm not so damn busy these next three weeks. I've bookmarked this request and will deal with it as soon as I can.